# GIMP filters throwing permission denied errors

Tags: permissions, gimp, manjaro, kde-plasma-5, image-filter

Using GIMP-2.10 on Manjaro KDE. The filters do work but throw this error whenever launched.

```
Failed to open file “/home/*USERNAME*/.config/GIMP/2.10/filters/GimpGegl-gegl-emboss-config.settings”: open() failed: Permission denied
```

Also, I cannot access any folder in `/home/*USERNAME*/.config/GIMP/2.10/`.

What might be the cause?

**Edit:** The permissions in that directory are:

```
ls -l
total 740
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   2186 Dec  4 19:04 action-history
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 backups
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 brushes
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    178 Dec  4 19:04 colorrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    300 Dec  4 19:04 contextrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   1783 Dec  4 19:04 controllerrc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 CrashLog
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 curves
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  20764 Dec  4 19:04 devicerc
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     57 Dec  4 19:04 dockrc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 dynamics
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 environ
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 filters
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 fonts
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 fractalexplorer
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 gfig
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 gflare
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    843 Nov 29 19:22 gimprc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 gimpressionist
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 gradients
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 icons
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 21  2019 internal-data
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 interpreters
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 levels
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  86473 Dec  4 19:04 menurc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 modules
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 palettes
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    102 Dec  4 19:04 parasiterc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 patterns
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 243906 Dec  4 18:27 pluginrc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 21  2019 plug-ins
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    209 Jun 16 17:06 print-page-setup
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    581 Jun 16 17:06 print-settings
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     62 Nov  3 20:31 profilerc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 scripts
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   3551 Dec  4 19:04 sessionrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 211350 Dec  4 19:04 tags.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  12205 Dec  4 19:04 templaterc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    304 Dec  4 18:27 themerc
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 themes
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 tmp
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 21  2019 tool-options
drw-r--r-- 2 myuser myuser   4096 May 19  2019 tool-presets
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   4136 Dec  4 19:04 toolrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   1217 Dec  4 19:04 unitrc
```

Comment: The cause is in the error message: permission denied. That's a problem because your user should have permissions in your home folder where the configuration folder is. Something messed with those permissions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've edited the post to include the permissions. What is the problem?

Comment: How is Gimp installed? As a regular package or as a snap or appimage or flatpak? Some of these limit by default the access to files.

Comment: @xenoid It's installed as a regular package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directories are missing the "execute" flags, so they cannot be traversed to open the files they contain. With `/home/*USERNAME*/.config/GIMP/2.10/` as the current directory, use

```
chmod +x */
```

... to set the execute flags on directories (in case of problems it might be worth checking that it is also set on the directories above: `/home/*USERNAME*/.config/GIMP` and `/home/*USERNAME*/.config/GIMP/2.10/`).

Also check that the files in `plug-ins` (binaries and python files) have the executable bit set.